# Using groupby().sum() on a dataframe, then plotting a pie chart with labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

This is my first question here, I'm quite new to Python/pandas/matplolib

I have this line of code that creates a DataFrame:

```
repartition = sorted2017.groupby(by=sorted2017["Traitement"]).sum()
```

It works as I expected, except that the column title "Traitement" seems to appear on its own row:

```
                  Prix  Coût net  Manuvie     CCQ  SSQ
Traitement                                            
masso (Véro)    213.86       0.0    144.0   69.86  0.0
ostéo (Véro)     80.00       0.0     64.0   16.00  0.0
physio (Danny)  415.00       0.0    265.0  150.00  0.0
physio (Véro)   269.00       0.0    204.8   64.20  0.0
psy (Simone)    500.00       0.0    150.0  350.00  0.0
psy (Véro)      300.00       0.0    240.0   60.00  0.0
```

I wanted to use the "Traitement" column as labels for my matplotlib pie chart, so I tried :

```
plt.pie(repartition["Prix"], labels=repartition["Traitement"])
```

plt.show()

But I get a KeyError. I've also tried with iloc for the labels, but then I get

> ValueError : "'label' must be of length 'x'"

How can I fix this?

Comment: repartition is not a DataFrame but a series. Can you provide the whole data, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `groupby`, `"Traitement"` column is in index column.

```
plt.pie(x=repartition["Prix"], labels=repartition.index)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be simple, but I didn't know where to look. You saved me a couple hours of looking everywhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Véronique Lamontagne glad it helped :)